# Parent object key of array that contains value with jq

Tags: jq

Say I have data something like this:

```json
{
  "18" : [ 2, 3, 3 ],
  "28" : [ 2, 2, 7 ],
  "45" : [ 3, 3, 5 ]
}
```

I'd like to make a `jq` query that returns the key/keys of the object with the array that contains a given value.  For example, 2 exists in keys "18" and "28", and 7 exists only exists in "28".  It is the name of the parent object I'm interested in finding.  I've been through the manual and I can't seem to find an example of anything like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `map_values` to `select` only the arrays that `contain` the given value `$val`, then pulling out the keys of those arrays:

```bash
jq -r --argjson val 2 'map_values(select(contains([$val]))) | keys[]' file
```

`contains()` returns *true* if the given array (`[$val]`) is fully contained in the input to the function.  If `contains()` returns *true* for an array in the input, `select()` will return that array.

I'm using `map_values()` to perform this selection of the arrays associated with the keys in the input object. This will give me a slimmed-down object with the arrays that pass the selection, and passing the result to `keys` will then give me an array of keys, which I unpack into a set of loose strings with the final `[]`.

For the given input data, with 2 as the value of `$val`, this returns

```
18
28
```

I'm using `--argjson` rather than `--arg` to pass the value 2 into the expression as `$val` as the data is numeric, not strings.

Comment: The answer is perfect, but I'm am still unclear what `map_values` is doing. The query cannot be run without it: 
```jq -r --argjson val 2 'select(contains([$val]))' test.json```
results in `jq: error (at test.json:4): object ({"18":[2,3,...) and array ([2]) cannot have their containment checked`.  And the manual for `map_values` isn't what I expect at all.

Comment: @A.Que `map_values()` works like `map()`, but takes an object as input rather than an array. The expression that `map_values()` evaluates is evaluated on the values in the object. In the answer above, I'm doing a `select()`, which effectively removes the values that we don't want to keep.